# Django: chaining 'startswith' and 'iexact' query filters?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to do do a case-insensitive `startswith` query in Django:

```
     books = Book.objects.filter(title__iexact__startswith=query)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
FieldError at /names/
Join on field 'title' not permitted
```

How can I specify a case-insensitive `startswith` in Django?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`istartswith`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith)